# What is the ConsumerConnectionPointID to use when adding an SSRS Report Viewer Web part declaratively?

Tags: web-part, reporting-services, connected-web-parts, connection

I'm having trouble connecting my custom web part to my report viewer web part when using XML markup.

My custom web part implements `ITransformableFilterValues`, so in order to pass values to the SSRS Report Webpart, I have this:

```
[ConnectionProvider("Region Filter", "ITransformableFilterValues", AllowsMultipleConnections = true)]
public ITransformableFilterValues SetConnectionInterface()
{
    return this;
}
```

The markup I have for connecting my custom webpart (provider) to the SSRS webpart (consumer) is this:

```
<AllUsersWebPart WebPartOrder="1" WebPartZoneID="RightColumn" ID="RowDimension">...</AllUsersWebPart>
<AllUsersWebPart WebPartOrder="2" WebPartZoneID="Body" ID="ReportViewer">...</AllUsersWebPart>
<WebPartConnection
  ID = "RowDimension_To_ReportViewer"
  ProviderID = "RowDimension"
  ProviderConnectionPointID = "ITransformableFilterValues"
  ConsumerID = "ReportViewer"
  ConsumerConnectionPointID="..."> <!-- <<--- WHAT GOES HERE??? --->
  <WebPartTransformer
    Assembly = "Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" Namespace = "Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages">
      <![CDATA[
        <WebPartPages:TransformableFilterValuesToFilterValuesTransformer MappedConsumerParameterName = "Param1" />
      ]]>
  </WebPartTransformer>
</WebPartConnection>
```

My test report has one parameter named 'Param1' that needs to receive from my custom provider webpart. I'm able to setup the connection manually (using Edit Webpart > Connections) and the report renders, but I'm not able to do it using the above markup.

What I'm missing is the value of the `ConsumerConnectionPointID` to provide. I tried the following:

- **BIDataProvider**
- **ReportParameters**
- **ITransformableFilterValues**
- and even **Param1** (the name of the consumer report parameter)

..but the report doesn't seem to be picking up the connection at all!

What's the expected value of `ConsumerConnectionPointID`?

**NOTE:**
Would it help if I mentioned that my custom provider web part is of type `System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.WebPart` and has `.webpart` type markup, while the SSRS web part uses `.dwp` markup since it is of type `Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPart`?